# New column based on presence of multiple value in others

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this `df`:

```
Plot <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
Dist <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,7,8,8,9,10)
df1 <- cbind(Plot, Dist)
```

And I would like to create a new column with different value in it, based on the `Dist`column.
So the final df would look like :

```
Plot <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
Dist <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,7,8,8,9,10)
Grp1 <- c("CT", "CT", "CT", "CT","CT","INT", "INT","INT", "INT", "EXT", "EXT","EXT", "EXT","EXT")
df2 <- cbind(Plot, Dist,Grp1)
```

I tried this approach :

```
library(dplyr) 

df<-df%>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  mutate(CT = if(any(Dist == 0), "CENTRE")) %>%
  mutate(CT = if(any(between(Dist, 1,7),"INTER"))) %>%
  mutate(CT = if(any(Dist > 7),"EXT"))
```

but I got the following : `Erreur : ',' inattendu(e) in "  mutate(CT = if(any(Dist> 7)`

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you have a dataframe, using `cbind` you are creating a matrix.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Plot, Dist)
```

Since every row has a different `Plot` value you don't need to `group_by` `Plot`. You can use `case_when` like :

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(CT = case_when(Dist == 0 ~ 'CENTRE', 
                        between(Dist, 1,7)~ "INTER", 
                        Dist > 7 ~ "EXT"))

#   Plot Dist     CT
#1     1    0 CENTRE
#2     2    0 CENTRE
#3     3    0 CENTRE
#4     4    0 CENTRE
#5     5    0 CENTRE
#6     6    1  INTER
#7     7    3  INTER
#8     8    4  INTER
#9     9    5  INTER
#10   10    7  INTER
#11   11    8    EXT
#12   12    8    EXT
#13   13    9    EXT
#14   14   10    EXT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a keys dataframe:

```
#Code
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
#Keys
keys <- data.frame(Dist=c(0:7))
keys$CT <- 'INTER'
keys$CT[keys$Dist==0]<-'CENTRE'
#Add
df1$CT<-keys[match(df1$Dist,keys$Dist),"CT"]
df1$CT[is.na(df1$CT)]<-'EXT'
```

Output:

```
df1
   Plot Dist     CT
1     1    0 CENTRE
2     2    0 CENTRE
3     3    0 CENTRE
4     4    0 CENTRE
5     5    0 CENTRE
6     6    1  INTER
7     7    3  INTER
8     8    4  INTER
9     9    5  INTER
10   10    7  INTER
11   11    8    EXT
12   12    8    EXT
13   13    9    EXT
14   14   10    EXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `ifelse` in this way;

```
df$Grp1 <- ifelse(df$Dist == 0, "CT", ifelse(df$Dist ==(1:5),"INT", "EXT"))
```

Don't forget to make it a `factor` and `relevel` if that is your intention. Here is one way you can do it.

```
df$Grp1 <- factor(df$Grp1)
df$Grp1 <- relevel(df$Grp1, ref="INT")
View(df)
```